# JSON arrays in R - {jsonlite}

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am currently writing a light API wrapper and having a minor headache around a JSON payload for a POST request.
Below you can find the required JSON structure to call the api:

```
{
    "points": [
        {
            "coord": [40.1, -73.0],
            "id": "test1"
        },
        {
            "coord": [37.784, -122.402]
        },
        {
            "coord": [41.84, -73],
            "id": "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here where I got to using `jsonlite`, what I'm struggling with is having `coord` values as an array (as of now I've just managed to parse them as a string). I am probably missing something fairly easy.

```r
library(jsonlite)

df <- data.frame(id = c(123, 456),
           coord = c("41.889083,12.470514",
                     "41.899009,12.477243"))

jsonified <- toJSON(list(`points` = df), pretty = T)

jsonified
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the coordinates into a list of string vectors of length 2. Make sure `coord` isn't a factor or convert it to character (I added `stringsAsFactor = FALSE` in creating the data frame).

```r
df$coord <- strsplit(df$coord, ",")
df
#>    id                coord
#> 1 123 41.889083, 12.470514
#> 2 456 41.899009, 12.477243

jsonlite::toJSON(list(`points` = df), pretty = TRUE)
#> {
#>   "points": [
#>     {
#>       "id": 123,
#>       "coord": ["41.889083", "12.470514"]
#>     },
#>     {
#>       "id": 456,
#>       "coord": ["41.899009", "12.477243"]
#>     }
#>   ]
#> }
```

Comment: After posting an answer, I found the question I flagged this as a duplicate of. I'm leaving my answer up for now but will gladly delete/welcome closing as duplicate if others agree